# Repeating Answer in Batch Random Number Generator

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, random

In my code*, I have a simple random number generator and a few ifs to check what number the generator produces. However, even when run in another instance of CMD, in another Batch file, and another instance of this Batch file, it still produces the same number: 4. Every time. I am not using this code in a loop, although it can be looped back to its section. I do, however, have another line of code to generate another number within a different set of parameters that works just fine.

*My code:

```
:genClass
set /a class=(5 * !random!) / 32768 + 1
if !class!==1 (
  set class=Knight
  goto genKnightArmor
)
if !class!==2 (
  set class=Warrior
  goto genWarriorArmor
)
if !class!==3 (
  set class=Archer
  goto genArcherArmor
)
if !class!==4 (
  set class=Thief
  goto genThiefArmor
)
if !class!==5 (
  set class=Mage
  goto genMageArmor
)

:genKnightArmor
set /a armor=(2 * !random!) / 32768 + 1
if !armor!==1 set armor=Light Armor
if !armor!==2 set armor=Heavy Armor
echo !name!
echo !gender!
echo !class!
echo !armor!
pause
exit

:genWarriorArmor
set /a armor=(2 * !random!) / 32768 + 1
if !armor!==1 set armor=Light Armor
if !armor!==2 set armor=Heavy Armor
echo !name!
echo !gender!
echo !class!
echo !armor!
pause
exit

:genArcherArmor
set /a armor=(2 * !random!) / 32768 + 1
if !armor!==1 set armor=Light Armor
if !armor!==2 set armor=Heavy Armor
echo !name!
echo !gender!
echo !class!
echo !armor!
pause
exit

:genThiefArmor
set /a armor=(2 * !random!) / 32768 + 1
if !armor!==1 set armor=Light Armor
if !armor!==2 set armor=Heavy Armor
echo !name!
echo !gender!
echo !class!
echo !armor!
pause
exit

:genMageArmor
set /a armor=(3 * !random!) / 32768 + 1
if !armor!==1 set armor=Light Armor
if !armor!==2 set armor=Heavy Armor
if !armor!==3 set armor=Robes and Hood
echo !name!
echo !gender!
echo !class!
echo !armor!
pause
exit
```

EDIT: With Monacraft's solution, it now generates a number of 2 and also generates the armor type without error. However, the code to generate the class is still messed up and, as stated before, continues to generate the number 2.

EDIT: I have edited the code once again to change the arithmetic and string variable names. This did not clear anything up, although the class generator is now continuously generating the number 3. I've noticed that, when edited, the generator produces a new number, although, after the first generation, it yields the same number.

EDIT: Fixed mistakes in my code. Such as matching the variables and changing the number 4 in the random generator to 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your expression

```
set /a num=(4 * !random!) / 32768 + 1
```

Batch mathematics is integer-only, so this will fail.

Try

```
set /a num=(%random% %% 4) + 1
```

Better yet, try in your main code

```
call :roll armor 3
```

and add at the end of the code

```
REM Roll 1..%2
:ROLL
set /a %1=(%random% %% %2) + 1
GOTO :EOF
```

Note carefully where the colons are - they are critical.

```
call :roll somevar n
```

will assign a random number 1..`n` to the variable `somevar`

Comment: No, the integer math works fine - it should give a value between 1 and 4. I agree it is much simpler to use modulo, but the original math should work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's working now, although it refrains from generating the number: 4 (Thief)... Any specific reason why? EDIT: Nevermind, made a typo!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the main problem with your random number generator is the use of `!` instead of `%`. Unless your using a `for` loop, you won't need these.

Instead of this:

```
set /a num=(4 * !random!) / 32768 + 1
```

Simply use this:

```
set /a num=(4 * %random%) / 32768 + 1
```

I tested this in cmd, and it worked fine.

To use `!` you need to `EnableDelayedExpansion` and then use this is a for loop.

Hope this helped with your problem,

Mona.

Answer (score 1):

```
set /a num=(4 * %random%) / 32768 + 1
if !class!==1 (
```

Maybe i'm wrong, but, `set num` and `if class` does not seem correct

Comment: lol Thanks for the notice! I guess I forgot to change that after doing some bug tests...

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do the selection:

```
@echo off
:genClass
set name=Slartibartfast
set gender=Alien
set /a num1=%random% %% 5 + 1

set /a num2=%random% %% 2 + 1
if %num1%==1 (
  set class=Knight
  if %num2%==1 set armor=Light Armor
  if %num2%==2 set armor=Heavy Armor
)

set /a num2=%random% %% 2 + 1
if %num1%==2 (
  set class=Warrior
  if %num2%==1 set armor=Light Armor
  if %num2%==2 set armor=Heavy Armor
)

set /a num2=%random% %% 2 + 1
if %num1%==3 (
  set class=Archer
  if %num2%==1 set armor=Light Armor
  if %num2%==2 set armor=Heavy Armor
)

set /a num2=%random% %% 2 + 1
if %num1%==4 (
  set class=Thief
  if %num2%==1 set armor=Light Armor
  if %num2%==2 set armor=Heavy Armor
)

set /a num2=%random% %% 3 + 1
if %num1%==5 (
  set class=Mage
  if %num2%==1 set armor=Light Armor
  if %num2%==2 set armor=Heavy Armor
  if %num2%==3 set armor=Robes and Hood
)

echo %name%
echo %gender%
echo %class%
echo %armor%
echo.
pause
goto :genclass
```